# jQuery scrollTo/localScroll Speed Control?

Tags: jquery, performance, scrollto

I am making a vertically scrolling site, but localScroll is flying by way too fast. Is there a way to control it's speed?

Comment: how did you do it?.. any codes?

Comment: Stack Overflows markdown is broken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you initialize localScroll, be sure to pass in duration:

```
$.localScroll({ duration: 500 });
```

On the help page for [`localScroll`](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) it specifies that you can additionally use all the options from [`scrollTo`](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

Comment: Hey guys, you're right, but you forgot to mention you need to load the easing plugin (http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) before you can call duration (or so it seems).

Comment: Easing is not specified in the default settings anywhere, so you should be able to do `{duration: 500, easing: "swing"}` and have it work w/o the easing plugin.

Answer (score 3):

To use localScroll with speed AND easing:
Import the jQuery, [scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/releases), [localScroll](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll/releases), and [easing](http://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.easing/) scripts.
Then put this script under it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#nav').localScroll({
            duration: 3000,
            easing: 'easeOutQuint'
        });
    });
</script>
```